# regex removing filename from path

Tags: regex, filenames, filepath

How could I design a RegEx script which would remove a filename from a path? The trick is, the paths have all sorts of wrenches to throw into the works.

Paths can consist of:

```
1: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3.1234/folder4.5678/ApplesandOranges.txt","MoreInfo","EvenMoreInfo"
2: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3.1234/folder4.91011/","MoreInfo","EvenMoreInfo"
```

or even

```
3: "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3.1234/folder4.5678/ApplesandOranges.zip?CatsAndDogs.txt","MoreInfo","EvenMoreInfo"
```

In cases 1 and 3, I'd like to end up with:

```
Folder1/Folder2/Folder3.1234/folder4.5678/
```

though, it would be acceptable for the second to return as

```
Folder1/Folder2/Folder3.1234/folder4.5678/ApplesandOranges.zip
```

though not preferred.

In case 2, it'd just skip that line entirely as there is no filename.

Any suggestions?

Using standard RegEx via a text editor. No java use and such.

Note: The path is just an example. There could be 50 folders. It's not a mere 4 folders all of the time

Comment: What about `s/.*\/(.*)/\1/`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
(.*\/).*
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO6xD8/2)**

[image]

As you can see, the idea is to capture all the content to the last slash by using `(.*\/)` and discard the rest `.*`. Check the substitution section above.

Comment: Ah...that would work but you just made me realize another piece of the puzzle. Updating my original post to reflect.

Comment: Actually, you know what, I can work with your answer. I'll just split my data file into two parts. One with everything but filepath, and one with just filepath and use your fix. Thanks!

Comment: Fede, sadly, no. However, I've come up with a solution based on your answer. I'll be marking answered. I'd upvote if I had the rep to do it!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this.

```
[^\/]+$
```

'$' matches the position at the end of the string while '[^/]+' matches any string that does not have any '/'.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
@"^.*[\/]"
```

[image: output result]