# Regex to extract last characters after underscore of folder name of full path

Tags: regex

I have two different regular expressions that almost do my task correctly. I am essentially trying to extract the last characters of a file's parent folder like this:

```
C:\home\username\folder_number_three\image.tif
```

to

```
three
```

I have used the regular expression `[^_]+$`, but this will only return three is there is no file name associated with the original string, i.e. `C:\home\username\folder_number_three`

I used the solution indicated here to strip the filename away, but I am having trouble combining these two solutions: [regex removing filename from path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796249/regex-removing-filename-from-path)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
_[^_\\.]+(?=$|\\[^_\\]+\.[^_\\]+$)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/eABKTH/1).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^_\\.]+                 any character except: '_', '\\', '.' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_\\]+                  any character except: '_', '\\' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_\\]+                  any character except: '_', '\\' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```